# Oracle can I use parallel hint in subquery?

Tags: oracle, performance, parallel-processing

I have many complex select statements to run, which will take at least 2 hours, and I want to speed up the query.
Can I use parallel hint both in subquery and mainquery to improve performance?
For example, is the following valid?

```
select /*+ parallel(32) */
    a.id,
    (select /*+ parallel(32) */ b.col1 from table b where b.id = a.id)
from 
(select /*+ parallel(32) */ c.id, c.col2 
 from table c) a
```

I am new to parallel hints. Thank you in advance for your advice.

Comment: what would be the sense? check exec plan for a query where you have parallel hint on the top level.

Answer (score 1):

That subquery returns a single row. You probably do not want that run in parallel, but you will probably find that using a conventional join allows better parallelism for the query.

```
select /*+ parallel(32) */
       c.id,
       b.col1
from   table c left join
       table b on b.id = c.id
```

Bear in mind that your maximum effective degree of parallelism is likely to be limited by your i/o bandwidth in this case, not by the usual "2 x cores" that is commonly used.